# Child of position: fixed; won't scroll

Tags: css

I have a sidebar with `position: fixed`. Inside this sidebar, I have a `.list` where I want to use `overflow: scroll`. However, it is not working as I want it to.

HTML

```
<div id="side">

    Stuff

    <div id="list">
        <div class="item">An item</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#side {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
}

#list {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;

    overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wGE9W/ (the yellow `list` won't scroll)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `height`:

```
#list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGE9W/1/)

> The height needs to be 100% – Patrick Reck 46 secs ago

Then why can't you just change it to that?

```
#list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGE9W/2/)

Comment: The height needs to be 100%